# Git branch push getting rejected by gerrit in egit

Tags: eclipse, git, egit, gerrit

We have gerrit configured for our git repository .I have created a new local branch.

Now i want to push the local branch into remote branch.
I am using egit. I clicked on push branch, push branch wizard came and i gave the the new branch name, push confirmation wizard gives the new branch name.

Now when i am trying to push it i get the following error

```
 prohibited by Gerrit
Processing changes: refs: 1
Processing changes: refs: 1, done
```

But i am able to push to my normal "master" branch.

Question is how gerrit takes the new branch which i am trying to push because it has not been created in remote

Best Regards,
Saurav

Comment: Please ask your gerrit administrator if your account is prohibited from creating/pushing new branches. Gerrit has some rules for access.

Comment: @ElpieKay thanks for the reply... Do i have to create a new gerrit branch ?...will anyways check my access rights ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have "Create Reference" permission for this repository.

See more info [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#category_create).

You need to talk to the Gerrit administrator. There're two options:

1. He can grant the "Create Reference" permission to you
2. He can create the new branch for you then you'll be able to push your commit to it

Comment: Yes got your point... i  asked my admin to create a branch...then i am able to proceed..